# DataTables jQuery library not working all the time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

I am using ***DataTables*** library to display a large amount of data ( 4000-5000 rows), the majority of data is fetched from a database.

Also, I am displaying an audio file on every row, these files are stored on the ***hard drive***.

The problem is that `DataTables` doesn't work all the time, meaning sometimes all the rows are displayed at once on the same page with no pagination.

I tried emptying the cache, it doesn't work.

what could be the problem?

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#datatableid').DataTable();
} );
</script>
```

[Here you can find the Console Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4YMm.png)

Comment: Firstly 5k rows is too much data. I'd strongly suggest you work with this server side and filter/page it to reduce the weight of data. Secondly, there's no way anyone can debug this given the little information in the question. I'd suggest checking the console for errors when it 'doesn't work' so you have something to diagnose.

Comment: Also note that the 'slim' branch of jQuery doesn't contain AJAX functions, so you may encounter issues with Datatables using it. I'd suggest using the standard version of jQuery for this.

Comment: you might need this.
https://datatables.net/manual/ajax